# Pick a random position in the word - IllegalArgumentException?

Tags: java, random, illegalargumentexception

I have to implement the following instructions (pseudocode):

```
Read a word.
Repeat word.length() times
   Pick a random position i in the word, but not the last position.
   Pick a random position j > i in the word. (this is a tricky point!)
   Swap the letters at positions j and i.
Print the word.
```

My code throws - [`IllegalArgumentException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) here:

`j = i + 1 + generator.nextInt( word.length() - i - 1 );`

I stack here and don't know how to circumvent this point.

**Code:**

```
public String scramble(String word) {
        Random generator = new Random(42);
        int x, i = 0, j = 0, wordLen = word.length();

        for (x = 0; x < wordLen; x++) {                
            i = generator.nextInt(wordLen);            
            j = i + 1 + this.generator.nextInt( word.length() - i - 1 );
        }
```

I can't find a good solution for this step:

> Pick a random position j > i in the word.

- How to solve this issue?

Comment: Just as an observation, the line `i = generator.nextInt(wordLen);` is wrong, since that can return `wordlen - 1`, which is the last position (and your directions say explictly not to)

Comment: @Dennis Meng `nextInt(n)` return on the border `0 ... n-1`

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int) - `IllegalArgumentException - if n is not positive`

Comment: @nazar_art Yes, and you don't want to be able to return `n-1` there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
generator.nextInt( word.length() - i - 1 );
```

would throw `IllegalArgumentException` incase the argument <= 0..

[From nextInt Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29)

> Throws:
>       IllegalArgumentException - if n is not positive

Check the `length` of a string before calling the line

---

You could do it this way

```
for (x = 0; x < wordLen; x++) {
      i = generator.nextInt(wordLen - 1); 
      j = generator.nextInt(wordLen);           
      if (j <= i)
        j = i + generator.nextInt(wordLen - i);
}
```

Comment: Correction: it throws IllegalArgumentException if the argument is less than **or** **equal** **to** zero (the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) says "if n is not positive").

Comment: @Anirudh How to circumvent this issue?

Comment: @Anirudh keep throwing `IllegalArgumentException` exception here - `j = generator.nextInt(i)+(wordLen-i);`

Comment: @nazar_art as i said i should be greater than 0!

Comment: @Anirudh it keeps throwing

Comment: @Anirudh What is `temp` here (contains)?

Answer (score 0):

```
String word = "Example"
int len = word.length(); //len = 7
int placeHolder1 = (int) (Math.random() * length); //generates number between 0 and 6
int placeHolder2 = (int) 
int diff = length - placeHolder1;
placeHolder2 = (int) (Math.random() * diff + (length - diff + 1)); //Generates random between placeHolder1 and the length of the String
```

This gives you the indices of two characters on the String, and you can swap them however you prefer.

Comment: You give some "bull" code: `int len = String.length()` how can it work?

Comment: My mistake, I'm typing on my machine w/o JDK, so did not test run code. I meant int len = word.length(), obviously.